# QDesktopServices::openUrl() doesn't open page in chrome on windows. Workaround?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, google-chrome

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"));
```

works if default browser ie9, ie8, firefox or opera

if default browser is chrome nothing happens

QtCreator debugger log i can see lines like

```
ModLoad: 00000000`05250000 00000000`05308000   iexplore.exe
```

or

```
ModLoad: 00000000`04db0000 00000000`04ef8000   chrome.exe
```

so it actually works, but ie, ff etc. opens new tab with specified url and chrome doesn't

i suppose it's bug

some time ago it worked perfectly

could it be problem with my system (ENV vars etc.)?

please help with workaround

i prefer crossplatform, but proper work on windows has max priority

possible solution (winapi SHELLEXECUTE) - really hate that way with ugly #ifdef, but can be an option

PS: sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it's really a problem of your application.. I think it's more about how Chrome is treated such invocations. Being on your place I would go for winpai SHELLEXECUTE solution. And #ifdef is not really ugly comparing with benefits that you move default browser invocation to operation system rather then on Qt library.

Comment: ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", qstring_to_wchar_t(url), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

not working neither

only

    ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", qstring_to_wchar_t(exe), qstring_to_wchar_t(params), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

where
exe - path to Chrome
params - "-- "http://www.google.com""

Comment: `ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", qstring_to_wchar_t(url), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` - doesn't work

`ShellExecute(NULL, L"runas", qstring_to_wchar_t(exe), qstring_to_wchar_t(params), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` - works, but asks elevated

Comment: exe - `"C:\Users\USER-01\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

params = `" -- "http://google.com""`

Comment: //According to <support.microsoft.com/kb/238245> ...
i know, `42` is OK, but chrome does nothing with `"open"`

Comment: nope, it opens new cmd window with title "http://google.com"
i know it' my computer issue, but it's rather common problem
and now problems with ie, ff and opera

Comment: i know,
real problem is that chrome brokes it
i need "silver bullet" for that